# How to hide keyboard done button in PhoneGap textarea?

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I have a text area which is in UIWebView ie., In PhoneGap plain html.
I want to hide the done previous/next buttons on focus of that text box.. how?!

Answer (score -4):

You want to read up on html controls of the keyboard in iOS:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: I am using as just same as in that doc. It's not working.. i couldn't hide the previous/next and done button :(

Comment: I am able hide it... But it is not allowed by Apple. Read the guidelines!